# Filtering datagridview with multiple combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to make a simple product code search using a datagridview.

I am able to filter the database but not able to get all the functions I want

I currently have it set as

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     productsBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("Type = '{0}'",
     comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
 }

 private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     productsBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("Type = '{0}' AND Fitting = '{1}'", 
     comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
     comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
 }
```

This code works but after the selections are made and I change `comboBox1` the data resets and doesn't keep the selection of `comboBox2`.

I understand in my current code that this would not happen but I cannot figure out how to get this to happen.

I would also like to add a text box in the future and have it narrow the filter even more.

Answer (score 0):

You should approach this a bit more generically like so

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FilterProducts();
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FilterProducts();
}

// Create a function to handle filters
private void FilterProducts() 
{
    string filter = "";
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null) 
    {
        filter += string.Format("Type = '{0}'", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }

    if (comboBox2.SelectedItem != null) 
    {
        if (filter.length > 0) filter += "AND "
        filter += string.Format("Fitting = '{0}'", comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }

    // Add another like above for your future textbox
    // if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) 
    // {
    //     if (filter.length > 0) filter += "AND "
    //     filter += string.Format("OtherColumn = '{0}'", textBox1.Text);
    // }

    productsBindingSource.Filter = filter;
}
```

The code could be further refactored for even better DRY standards but this should at least get you started.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you have a moment be sure to click the check box on the left below the up and down vote arrows.

Comment: @AndreTurgeon - please tick the holo checkbox to let everyone this question is answered. Ticking it will give you a couple of rep points.